groupby multiple columns, while sum the numeric ones, from a pandas DataFrame
So... I have a DataFrame like this
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('data.csv'))
    df_VxM = df.loc[:,['Brand', 'Code', 'Sells1', 'Sells2']]

How can I group all the rows with same 'Code' value, while summing the sells and not losing the 'Brand' value nor changing it.
I tried using
  df_VxM.groupby(['Brand', 'Code'], sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
  df_VxM.drop_duplicates().groupby('Brand', 'Code').sum()

The current output is just a traceback:
" 'DataFrameGroupby' object has no attribute 'groupby' "
I expected something like .drop_duplicates, with both columns, without losing the info. in any 'SellsX' column, thing that does not happend with .drop_duplicates either

What is the exact expected output?

Do you want df.groupby(['Brand', 'Code'], as_index=False, sort=False)[['Sells1', 'Sells2', 'TotalSell']].sum()?

Hello Melissa, sorry it is not clear what is desired output. Why the approach with groupby didn't work for you?

The expected output is just one row for 'Code', while keeping the info of sell.
And my attempt with groupby throws a traceback, that's why I'm not sure if is a syntax mistake

Please be explicit, [edit] the question, provide the exact expected output in the same format as the input.

Also be aware that you example no longer has a "Code" column.

IIUC, you want to perform a groupby operation and grab the sum of each of the groups while also preserving the original ordering. You can accomplish this by passing .groupby(..., sort=False, as_index=False)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Brand':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'Code':['aba', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'bbb'],
    'Sells1':[3, 5, 7, 1],
    'Sells2':[9, 8, 1, 0],
})

print(
    df.groupby(['Brand', 'Code'], sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
)
#   Brand Code  Sells1  Sells2
# 0     A  aba       3       9
# 1     B  bbb       6       8
# 2     A  aaa       7       1


I got the same traceback: " 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no atribute 'groupby'"

did you copy and paste the code exactly as it is written? It seems like the code you are running is different. Have you done something like this by mistake: df = df.groupby(...) then later tried df.groupby(...).sum()?

Yea, my actual code is quite bigger, that's why I tried with pandas, I'm a newbie. Ande, yes to the first part, I did the df = df.groupby(...), but not the later

Note
You are applying the groupby() method on a DataFrameGroupBy object, itself, which is not right. Because groupby() is a method of the DataFrame object, not the DataFrameGroupBy.

You can use merge() and drop the duplicates with drop_duplicates():
import pandas as pd

D = {
    'Brand': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
    'Code': ['123', '456', 'aaa', '456', 'aaa'],
    'Sells1': [4, 0, 9, 0, 9],
    'Sells2': [8, 24, 6, 24, 6],
    'TotalSell': [12, 24, 12, 24, 12]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(D)
GB = df.groupby('Code', as_index=False).sum()
res = pd.merge(GB, df[['Code', 'Brand']].drop_duplicates(), on='Code', how='left')

# print(res)
res['Brand'] = res['Brand_y']
res = res.drop(columns=['Brand_x', 'Brand_y'])
res = res[['Brand', 'Code', 'Sells1', 'Sells2', 'TotalSell']]

print(res)


Prints
  Brand Code  Sells1  Sells2  TotalSell
0     A  123       4       8         12
1     B  456       0      48         48
2     A  aaa      18      12         24


res = df.groupby(['Code', 'Brand'], as_index=False).sum() would give the same output, there is no points in all the merge/drop_duplicates/…

@mozway You are right. Overall, I'm not sure what the expected output is.

Sorry, I already added the expected output

@melgibsonuwu That's okay. In that case, the first comment in this answer is what you want. Right?

Not really, it's basically what I've already tried. I think that there is some typo in the actual code. It's such a shame I can't share it... :<

@melgibsonuwu Can you edit your question and add part of the traceback that you get in your question? For example, ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length? or name 'null' is not defined or TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' or SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?, etc...

I already added as close as I can to the real deal, I hope is better at illustrating the issue

@melgibsonuwu Updated. You should apply groupby(), directly to DF.
